# PHP unset session in method

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, session

i have created a custom class to manage all types of session

i have created few static methods but for unset its giving me an error

```
 public static function unsetSession($para) {

     return unset($_SESSION[$para]);

    }
```

Can nay one give an idea why its throwing error

I read php document

**Description**

```
void session_unset ( void )
```

The `session_unset()` function frees all session variables currently registered.

**Return Values**

No value is returned.

is it unset is not returning ?

Thanks

Getting following Error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET)

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta.updated question

Comment: Is this to do with codeigniter or laravel two different frameworks

Comment: If codeigniter https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: @wolfgang1983.i am using core php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
public static function unsetSession($para) {
    return session_unset($_SESSION[$para]);
}
```

Comment: @carl.ya thats working may i know why unset is not working

Comment: Because `unset` is not even a function. And based from your description, it is clearly said that "The `session_unset()` function frees all session variables currently registered."

Answer (score 2):

`unset()` destroys the specified variables.

The behavior of `unset()` inside of a function can vary depending on what type of variable you are attempting to destroy.

`If a globalized variable is unset() inside of a function, only the local variable is destroyed`. The variable in the calling environment will retain the same value as before unset() was called.

Read here : [unset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)